# Payment integration on firebase android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, payment-gateway

I am working on a project using firebase and Android but the only gateway available is stripe. Since its not available in India I require something that is compatible to India. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The [`function-samples` repository](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) contains examples of processing payments with Stripe and Paypal. You can use those samples as inspiration for any other payment provider, since the approach is similar between all of them. If you're having trouble making your chosen payment provider work, post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful). Beyond that: recommending a specific provider or implementation is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe is already available in India, but just in case that you want to work with an indian company, maybe Razorpay could help you. They only operate in India for the moment.
Here is the link https://razorpay.com/